# Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

everyone, I am trying to write a unit test for my Processor class. in my project, I take a JSON file and Deserialize it and then I build and process it then save it to my database 
this is my process class

```
public class CustomerProcessors
    {
        private static IRepository _repository;
        private static PracticeEntities4 _context;
        private static Customer customer;
        public CustomerProcessors()
        {
        }

        public CustomerProcessors(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }


        public static void Process(Customer customer)
        {
            var oldcustomer = _repository.GetOldCustomerId(customer.Code.Value);
          if (oldcustomer == null)
            {
                Save(customer);
            }
            else
                update(customer);
        }

        private static void update(Customer customer)
        {

            _repository.UpdateCustomer(customer);

        }

        private static void Save(Customer customer)
        {
            _repository.SaveCustomer(customer);
        }
    }
```

this is my Builder

```
 public  Customer CustomerBuild(DtoCustomer dto)
        {
            return new Customer()
            {
                FirstName = dto.FirstName,
                LastName = dto.LastName,
                Address = dto.Address,
                Email = dto.Email,
                Code = int.Parse(dto.Code),
                PhoneNumber = dto.Phone

            };
        }
```

and finally, this is my unit test

```
    [TestClass]
   public class CustomerProcessorTest
    {

        private static string path;
        private static CustomerDeserializer _customerDeserializer;
        private static CustomerBuilder _customerBuilder;
        private List<Customer> _customers;
        private static Mock<IRepository> mock;
        private  Customer customer;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void CLassInitialize(TestContext context)
        {
            path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"JSON\", "Customer.json");
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestInitialize()
        {
            mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
            _customerDeserializer = new CustomerDeserializer();
            _customerBuilder = new CustomerBuilder();
            _customers = new List<Customer>();
            Customer customer = new Customer();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CusomerDeserialize_customerProcess()
        {
            //Arange
            mock.Setup(e => e.GetOldCustomerId(1001)).Returns(3);
            mock.Setup(e => e.GetOldStoreId(200)).Returns(3);
            //Act
            var dtos = CustomerDeserializer.Deserialize(path);
            var dto = dtos.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == "1001");
            var Builder= new CustomerBuilder();
            var customer = Builder.CustomerBuild(dto);
//Error here
                var process= CustomerProcessors.Process(customer);

            //Asset
            Assert.AreEqual(0, _customers.Count);
        }


    }
}
```

I have this error and I don't know what to do?

Comment: `CustomerProcessors.Process` is declared `void`. It doesn't return anything so there's nothing to assign to a local variable, and no type for `var` to infer.

Comment: how can i change that?

Comment: What do you expect the variable `process` to contain?

Comment: it is for saving or updating one customer to the database I wrote the methods to do that now I want to call them and use them

Comment: We can see what it does. That's clear. What it *doesn't* do is return a value, and yet you attempt to assign a non-existent return value to a variable. So to repeat Sweeper's question, *"what do you expect the variable `process` to contain?"* If you really do expect it to contain something, `Process` needs to return that instead of being `void`. If `Process` is fine as `void`, don't try to assign its non-existent return value to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line if code

```
var process= CustomerProcessors.Process(customer);
```

To this:

```
CustomerProcessors.Process(customer);
```

This way the function will be executed. You are now trying to assign void (nothing) to something so the compiler complains.

Doing this change, means that you will not actually test anything other than that your code does not throw an exception.

If you change the line to

```
// I removed the static identifier
// I added a boolean indicating success
public bool Process(Customer customer)
```

Then there is a value to test and assert based on conditions and you can reintroduce the process var

#### Edit for null point exception

Your problem stems from your repository being null. To solve it, make the following changes

```
public void Process(Customer customer)
```

And in your tests

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void CusomerDeserialize_customerProcess()
        {
            //Arange
            mock.Setup(e => e.GetOldCustomerId(1001)).Returns(3);
            mock.Setup(e => e.GetOldStoreId(200)).Returns(3);
            //Act
            var dtos = CustomerDeserializer.Deserialize(path);
            var dto = dtos.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == "1001");
            var Builder= new CustomerBuilder();
            var customer = Builder.CustomerBuild(dto);

            // create an instance of the processor
            var processor = new CustomerProcessors(mock.Object);
            // execute the function
            processor.Process(customer);

            //Asset
            Assert.AreEqual(0, _customers.Count);
        }
```

Comment: if I do that I get this error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. this is why I wanted  to do it different